# Reading input line and parsing it into STL storage c++

Tags: c++

I need to write a program that can read user input and store it. The information user will provide is a puzzle piece. The information will be in format:

```
piece 2 12:244:2333:78:as=fs/ sf
```

where `piece` is the command to store the information, 2  is the id_number of the puzzle, first for string separated by ":" are the puzzles sides(give information which puzzle piece fits where) and lastly there are 3 3 character groups which are the "picture of the puzzle". Basically I need to store the id, sides and the picture of the puzzle for further use. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

First you can make a class to hold your data:

```
class Piece {
public:
  int id_number;
  int sides[4];
  char picture[3][3];
};
```

Next you can define a stream operator to read it:

```
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream& in, Piece& piece) {
  in >> piece.id_number;
  in >> piece.sides[0];
  in >> piece.sides[1];
  // ...
  return in;
}
```

Then you can read a piece from standard input like this:

```
std::string name;
if (cin >> name) {
  if (name == "piece") {
    Piece piece;
    cin >> piece;
    // do something with piece
  }
}
```